# Windows 10 won't go to sleep after Youtube stopped playing

Tags: windows-10, sleep

My sleep mode works perfect in normal conditions, but after youtube stopped playing a movie, he won't go to sleep. Any possible solutions?

Kind regards
Gino

Comment: Are you talking about a timed sleep after X time of inactivity? If so that is to be expected as certain pages prevent that from happening for obvious reasons. You can't have both.

Comment: Please run commands as admin: 

***powercfg -requests.***  

The Request switch lists application and driver power requests. These requests prevent the computer from powering of the display or entering sleep. The RequestsOverride switch sets a power request override for a particular process, service or driver. This enables the PC to sleep even when there are current requests that would ordinarily prevent display power-off or sleep. 
Usage:
POWERCFG -REQUESTSOVERRIDE <CALLER_TYPE> <NAME> <REQUEST>

Comment: @KateLi since your comment resolved the problem I think that you should repost your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please run commands as admin: 
powercfg -requests.

The Request switch lists application and driver power requests. These requests prevent the computer from powering of the display or entering sleep. The RequestsOverride switch sets a power request override for a particular process, service or driver. This enables the PC to sleep even when there are current requests that would ordinarily prevent display power-off or sleep.

Usage:

POWERCFG -REQUESTSOVERRIDE CALLER_TYPE NAME REQUEST